# Reverse an ASCII string using C macros only

Tags: c, string, macros, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am trying to output Hebrew words in Pebble that are given as ISO-8859-8 encoded char* in C code, however I need to turn them into ISO-8859-8-L encoded strings. This basically means reversing the strings:

```
"ABC D" => "D CBA"
```

The input strings are 8-bit ASCII (no multi-byte or unicode).
I know how to do in-place reversion of the strings in C code, but then I need to reverse all strings in the init() function, so I wonder if there's a way to define a C macro to do it.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way for a C macro to break down a string literal into parts, which is what you'd need. Does it really have to be a macro?

Comment: As I wrote in the question I'm looking for an optimisation in order not to do it in the init() function, because then I'd have to totally reorganise all the strings in this watchface (which was written by someone else, I'm just trying to display the texts in Hebrew)

Comment: Is this for simple console display or something more advanced? There must be standard methods for writing right to left. Just convert to Unicode and print out.

Comment: Well in iconv I could only find how to convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-8, but not to ISO-8859-8-L (I'm not even sure if the last letter is supposed to be capital L, small L, capital I or the number 1, but I tried all of them and iconv doesn't know the encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any use of the CPP for reversing a string.

You could certainly use a function-like macro, as below.

```
#define rev_str(string, len) do {               \
    int i;                                      \
    for(i = 0; i < len>>1; ++i) {               \
        const uint8_t t = string[len - i - 1]]; \
        string[len - i - 1] = string[i];        \
        string[i] = t;                          \
    }                                           \
} while(0)
```

But then I don't see what advantage this has over being an inline function.

On the other hand, if you want to defer this to compile-time (and wanting it to use only macros makes me think you might), I believe you would need something beyond the scope of the CPP, such as C++'s template metaprogramming.

Comment: Yes, my intention was to do it compile-time if possible, by only adding something like HE("...") around the existing strings. Maybe I'll need to reogranise all the strings into 1 file then use iconv or something similar on it. Or I'll just manually reverse the strings :(